# Problem arising when make ROSARIA

Tags: rosaria, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosaria installation is successful, but when type catkin_make, the command line shows that:
~/src/rosaria/RosAria.cpp:6:25: fatal error: Aria/Aria.h: could not find such file or directory : Aria/Aria.h

compilation terminated.

make[2]: *** [rosaria/CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/RosAria.cpp.o] error 1

make[1]: *** [rosaria/CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/all] error 2

How to solve it? Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196759/problem-arising-when-make-rosaria/) by [yujunzeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/20694/yujunzeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-11-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2014-12-03**:
The ARIA library should have been downloaded and installed when you used `rosdep update` and `rosdep install rosaria` (http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA).   What was the output of those commands, any errors?

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2014-12-03**:
Note that `rosdep install rosaria` builds and installs ARIA differently than the normal package from Adept MobileRobots.   You can skip that if you want, in which case RosAria should when built use the normal Adept install location /usr/local/Aria instead... but either way ARIA needs to be installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Provide more details about the system and ROS distro you are using. It seems you do not have your ros workspace properly configured or you are not installing in the ros workspace. Are you sourcing the setup.bash file in your catkin_ws/devel folder properly?

---

Originally posted by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) with karma: 340 on 2014-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1